# How can I Find / replace a nondescript number with a formatted date in a file, in Applescript?

Tags: date, replace, find, applescript, automator

I've looked everywhere and I can't seem to find the exact answer I need.

I am creating a applescript in automator to FIND a nondescript number / date then I need it to replace that number with a formatted date.

So ex.  In a file I get from Person A, they format todays date in the file as 230629_TO_SS_PACKAGE_001. I need a script that will find that date / numbers and change it to a different format of todays Date.  So it needs to be DDMMYYYY 29062023_TO_SS_PACKAGE_001.

I have this apple script I found online to help me replace a word in another daily doc I receive and it works perfect. But now I just need it to find the date / nondescript number and replace it with the formatted today's date DDMMYYYY.

```
set stringToFind to "THIS WORD"  
set stringToReplace to "THIS NEW WORD"  
set theFile to choose file  
set theContent to read theFile as «class utf8»  
set {oldTID, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to 
{AppleScript's   text item delimiters, stringToFind}  
set ti to every text item of theContent  
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to stringToReplace  
set newContent to ti as string  
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldTID  
try  
    set fd to open for access theFile with write permission.       
    set eof of fd to 0  
    write newContent to fd as «class utf8»  
    close access fd  
on error  
    close access theFile     
end try
```

So I would need
set stringToFind to find the 230629_
and then set stringToReplace to today's date 29062023_ (formatted date DDMMYYYY)

Any help would be truly appreciated.  Thank you!!

Comment: The number strings will always be todays date, just in the wrong format?

Comment: @red_menace yes.  The editor puts the date incorrectly on the txt file. And there are 70 rows sometimes with other info in each row.  And I have to replace the date for each row. I tried bbedit but I have to highlight each date to change date individually because txt file will highlight whole page.  We use the date it was submitted to us, so generally that would be 'today's' date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **SED** command to simplify the solution.

```
set theFile to (choose file)
set posixPath to quoted form of (POSIX path of theFile)
set theContent to read theFile as «class utf8»

set newText to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of theContent & ¬
    " | sed -E 's/([0-9][0-9])([0-9][0-9])([0-9][0-9])_/ \\3\\220\\1_/g' > " & posixPath
```

In the SED expression,
([0-9][0-9]) is 2 digits group (you need 3 groups, followed by _ symbol)

This groups are replaced in / \3\220\1_/g part

Is added the Space & 20 & added groups in other order (not 1,2,3 but 3,2,1)

**Simplified test:**

```
set theContent to "file230629 as 230629_TO_SS_PACKAGE_001. I need a script"

set newText to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of theContent & ¬
    " | sed -E 's/([0-9][0-9])([0-9][0-9])([0-9][0-9])_/ \\3\\220\\1_/g' "

--> "file230629 as 29062023_TO_SS_PACKAGE_001. I need a script"
```

Comment: Hi Robert, Thanks for the help, unfortunately because my document has a lot of numbers in it the above worked, but changed a lot of the other numbers in the txt file.  The date in the txt is the only number set formatted as 230706_ so I was hoping to find / create a script that will find any number formatted as ######_ then replace it with a formatted 'today's date' as 06072023_

Comment: I've made the necessary changes to my answer. Now the **SED** command will only act on **groups of 6 digits** ending with the character **"_"**

Answer (score 0):

For stuff like this, I prefer using an [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date string, as it is a standard format that doesn’t change with locale or date preference.  AppleScript can get this string from a built-in ISO date class (although it is a bit obscure), where it can be rearranged however you want.

The following example can be used with your existing script:

```
set ISODate to (current date) as «class isot» as string -- today's date/time as YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss
log result
tell ISODate
   set stringToFind to text 3 thru 4 & text 6 thru 7 & text 9 thru 10 & "_" -- "YYMMDD_"
   set stringToReplace to text 9 thru 10 & text 6 thru 7 & text 1 thru 4 & "_" -- "DDMMYYYY_"
end tell
log stringToFind & " -> " & stringToReplace
```